# Different user access to different sharepoint views

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a sharepoint list with 10 columns. I want to give access to two different users.
User 1- Can edit all 10 columns.
User 2- Can only edit 6 columns.

Comment: You want to show different list views/columns to users OR different fields on list forms for editing/adding new items?

Answer (score 0):

There is no directly way could do this in SharePoint online modern experience.

As a workaround, we suggest you add the different list view web part in classic page,then set Target Audiences for different web parts.

[image]